# C: Occurrence of Letters in Text file

Tags: c

Program takes an input file through the command line and outputs the occurrence of each letter in the text file. Not sure where I went wrong.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char word[1000];
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int h = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int o = 0;
    int p = 0;
    int q = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int t = 0;
    int u = 0;
    int v = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    int other = 0;

    int counter, lenght;

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    fgets(word, 999, fp);

    lenght = 1000;
    for(counter = 0; counter < lenght; counter++) {
        word[counter] = tolower(word[counter]);
        if (word[counter] == 'a') {
            a++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'b') {
            b++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'c') {
            c++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'd') {
            d++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'e') {
            e++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'f') {
            f++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'g') {
            g++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'h') {
            h++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'i') {
            i++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'j') {
            j++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'k') {
            k++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'l') {
            l++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'm') {
            m++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'n') {
            n++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'o') {
            o++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'p') {
            p++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'q') {
            q++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'r') {
            r++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 's') {
            s++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 't') {
            t++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'u') {
            u++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'v') {
            v++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'w') {
            w++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'x') {
            x++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'y') {
            y++;
        }
        else if (word[counter] == 'z') {
            z++;
        }
        else {
            other++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nCharacter frequency in %s", argv[1]);
    printf("\nCharacter   Count");
    printf("\na \t\t %d", a);
    printf("\nb \t\t %d", b);
    printf("\nc \t\t %d", c);
    printf("\nd \t\t %d", d);
    printf("\ne \t\t %d", e);
    printf("\nf \t\t %d", f);
    printf("\ng \t\t %d", g);
    printf("\nh \t\t %d", h);
    printf("\ni \t\t %d", i);
    printf("\nj \t\t %d", j);
    printf("\nk \t\t %d", k);
    printf("\nl \t\t %d", l);
    printf("\nm \t\t %d", m);
    printf("\nn \t\t %d", n);
    printf("\no \t\t %d", o);
    printf("\np \t\t %d", p);
    printf("\nq \t\t %d", q);
    printf("\nr \t\t %d", r);
    printf("\ns \t\t %d", s);
    printf("\nt \t\t %d", t);
    printf("\nu \t\t %d", u);
    printf("\nv \t\t %d", v);
    printf("\nw \t\t %d", w);
    printf("\nx \t\t %d", x);
    printf("\ny \t\t %d", y);
    printf("\nz \t\t %d", z);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Should output in two columns one being the letter and the next being the number of times that letter occurs

Comment: Yikes. Well first you could use some for loops and store the characters in an array, so `A[25]={0};` would help quite a bit. Break the letters down to their respective position in the array using an ascii table and increment each spot respectively.

Comment: `Should output in two columns one being the letter and the next being the number of times that letter occurs` Right. And what is it doing?

Comment: @Chirality: you mean `int A[26] = { 0 };` ?

Comment: @chqrlie  Yeah I forgot my alphabet for a quick second!

Answer (score 5):

There are problems in your code:

- you do not include `<stdio.h>` nor `<ctype.h>`
- you only read one line and you do not even check if that succeeds. You should write a loop like `while (fgets(word, sizeof word, fp)) {`
- you check all characters in the `word` array: you should stop at the end of the line: `lenght = strlen(word);`
- `tolower()` should not be given a `char` argument, because on platforms where `char` is signed, negative values invoke undefined behavior.  You can cast the argument as `(unsigned char)` to avoid this: `word[counter] = tolower((unsigned char)word[counter]);`

More room for improvement:

- `lenght` is misspelt, it should be `length`.
- you should use an array of counters to avoid all these tests and all these explicit `printf` statements.
- check the argument count and `fopen()` success
- no need to read line by line, handle one byte at a time read with `getc()`. However, reading one large chunk at a time can be faster because it uses fewer tests and locks.
- the `printf` statements should output the newline at the end rather than at the beginning.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int count[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { 0 };
    int other, total;
    int c;
    const char *s;
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc <= 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing input file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    total = 0;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        count[tolower(c)] += 1;
        total++;
    }

    printf("Character frequency in %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("Character   Count\n");
    other = total;
    for (s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; *s; s++) {
        printf("%c:\t%9d\n", *s, count[(unsigned char)*s]);
        other -= count[(unsigned char)*s];
    }
    printf("other:\t%9d\n", other);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Reading the file by chunks instead of one byte at a time improves the speed dramatically with recent C libraries, because the support for multithreading has made the `getc()` macros inefficient.  Using 64K buffers, the code below is **fifty times faster (50X)** for a 400MB file:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 65536
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    long count[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { 0 };
    long other;
    size_t i, n;
    const char *s;
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc <= 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing input file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while ((n = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fp)) != 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            count[buffer[i]] += 1;
        }
    }
    other = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++) {
        if (isupper(i)) {
            count[tolower(i)] += count[i];
        } else {
            if (!islower(i))
                other += count[i];
        }
    }

    printf("Character frequency in %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("Character   Count\n");
    for (s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; *s; s++) {
        printf("%c:\t%9ld\n", *s, count[(unsigned char)*s]);
    }
    printf("other:\t%9ld\n", other);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the print statements should end with a newline, rather than begin with one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: absolutely.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: too bad the `getc()` macros are no longer efficient (and no longer macros).  Even with multithread support, they could still be made as fast as they used to be.

Comment: On POSIX-ish systems, the required locking adds overhead that presumably has been measured and makes the macros less effective than using a function.  Try [`getc_unlocked()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getc_unlocked.html) — on a Mac, that is still a macro: `int c = getc_unlocked(stdin);` expands to `int c = (--(__stdinp)->_r < 0 ? __srget(__stdinp) : (int)(*(__stdinp)->_p++));`, which is similar to what `getc()` used to expand to back in the days when CPUs had single cores.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I tried `getc_unlocked()`: the program is 8 times faster than using `getc()` for the same 400MB file. My idea is that even on systems that provide locking, as is mandatory now, the `getc()` could still be implemented like `getc_unlocked()`: it would suffice to always set `(__stdinp)->_r` to `0` once multiple threads are started, `_r` members would also need to be cleared for open streams when the second thread is started. A separate counter would be used by `__srget()`.

Comment: 'Tis interesting that the result is so much faster (8 times is a lot).  Once you're calling a function (`__srget()`), you can do the locking 'properly'.  Having `pthread_create()` find all the open file streams and set the `_r` member to a negative number would be fiddly — not undoable, but fiddly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `fopen()` and friends would keep open streams in a doubly linked list.  This trick way provide for substantial speed improvements on programs without threads. I have seen much fiddlier stuff for much less purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick implementation I wrote. It doesn't use fgets, but that is most definitely an option.

The flow of the program should be simple, but it is as follows:

- Check for a proper argument count.
- Declare the variables we'll need.
- Declare the file pointer and attempt to open the file.
- If the file doesn't open, we'll error out.
- Read in every character from the file one at a time and store it into our variable `c`.
- Using our ascii table, we'll alter the values to get them into the proper position in our array.
- Print out all of our values.
- Close the file.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(int argc, char **argv){

      if (argc < 2){
          printf("Not enough arguments!\n");
          return -1;
      }

      int A[27] = {0}, c;

      FILE *inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      if (inFile == NULL){
          printf("The file \"%s\" could not be opened.\n", argv[1]);
          return -2;
      }

      while((c = fgetc(inFile)) != EOF){
          if ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ){
              /* C is a lowercase character */
              c-='a'; 
              A[c]++;
          }
          else if ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ){
              /* C is an uppercase character */
              c-='A';
              A[c]++;
          }
          else if (c == '\n'){
              /* we're not counting newlines */
              continue;
          }
          else {
              A[26]++;
          }
      }

      /* Print out all the values except the "Other" count. */
      for (c = 0; c < sizeof A / sizeof A[0] - 1; c++){
              printf("%c: %d\n", c+'a', A[c]);
      } printf("Other: %d\n", A[26]); //Print out "Other" count

      /* Close our file */
      fclose(inFile);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Your program is hard coded for ASCII, letters are not necessarily contiguous.  Even assuming ASCII, you should use `'a'` and `'z'` instead of their numeric value.

Comment: character constants are more readable indeed, but your code still assumes ASCII as it would fail if letters were not a contiguous block. EBCDIC does not have this.